# How to Retrieve Blogger JSON Data inside Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, blogger

This is my Blogger JSON Link for specific label: http://www.filmsbit.com/feeds/posts/default/-/Movies?published&alt=json-in-script

I want to JSON Data inside Javascript in my page like this:

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
     var bh_main_vars = {"bh_default_playlist":

 [{"id":postID,title:"PostTitle","poster":"MediaThumbnail","Label":"PostLabel","link":"postLink"},

{"id":postID,title:"PostTitle","poster":"MediaThumbnail","Label":"PostLabel","link":"postLink"}]};
    </script>
```

THanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think fetch is simplest way.

```
var bh_main_vars;
fetch("/feeds/posts/default/-/Movies?published&alt=json-in-script")
.then(response => {
   bh_main_vars = JSON.parse(response.json)}
)
```

It should work but I wrote it from phone

Comment: thanks your ans. but its not work. can you tell me more about this. i am very new in javascript and json

Comment: May be i am not able to understand about what i need. thanks